# Google Drive API: Select files and folders which are shared publicly

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to request only the files which are publicly shared for reading, i.e. they have `"id":"anyone", "type":"anyone", "role":"reader"` in their permissions, via the `q` parameter to `Files.list`.

`"q": "<id or name or email> in readers"` works for actual users, but `"q":"anyone" in readers` always returns an empty result.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I tried playing with the [available field parameter options](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) but I can't see any field that you can use in q parameter to filter publicly shared files.

The best option you have right now is to manually filter the result. You need to check files with permissions type set to "anyone".